# Sort list by member variables correctly

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I am trying to sort a list of objects by member variable. Going through stack overflow, I have found the following method. However, *lsort* Compares digit by digit, so that 5, 3, 7, 21, 64 will sort to 21, 3, 5, 64, 7 (I would like this to be numeric: 3, 5, 7, 21, 64). I am unsure of how to fix this, because some keys may look like D239, D97, D11 (*lsort* on this will look like D11, D239, D97; I would like it to look like D11, D97, D239). Though I prefer one method, I guess two would be ok.

```
import operator 

class foo:
    def __init__(self, key1, data1, data2):
        #all of these values are strings, even though some may be ints
        self.key = key1
        self.d1 = data1
        self.d2 = data2

#sorts list l by member variable search
def lsort (l, search):
    #this doesn't actually work very well.
    #key can be int or string
    #when key is an int, this seems to order by number of digits, then low to high
    #(e.g. 11, 12, 40, 99, 3, 6, 8)
    return sorted(l, key=operator.attrgetter(search))


l1 = [foo('12', 'foo1', None), foo('8', 'qwer', None), foo('7', 'foo3', None), foo('13', 'foo2', None), foo('77', 'foo4', None), foo('12', 'foo5', None) ]


for item in lsort(l1, 'key'):
    print item.key, item.d1, item.d2
```

OUTPUT:

```
12 foo1 None 
12 foo5 None 
13 foo2 None
7 foo3 None
77 foo4 None
8 qwer None
```

EXPECTED:

```
7 foo3 None
8 qwer None
12 foo1 None
12 foo5 None
13 foo2 None
77 foo4 None
```

Why is this happening? I use the same sort and run it on an extremely basic class and it seems to be working fine.

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, d1):
        self.bar= d1
```

Please assist. Thanks.

Comment: What order do you want, exactly? For example, if the values are `'22'`, `'2x'`, and `'3'`, what order should those be in? If you do a numeric comparison between `'22'` and `'3'`, `'3'` comes before `'22'`, but then placing `'2x'` is awkward.

Comment: I have an expected results portion in the above. I would like the list to be sorted by numerically by key, so 1, 5, 8, 10, 15, 33, 65, etc. I'll change it to be  more clear.

Comment: if you know that the `key` parameter will always be an int or a string that represents an int, you can do an explicit cast when you set the key in your `init` like `self.key = int(key1)`. this will give you the right output but will fail if key cannot be cast to an int

Comment: Perhaps it'll be interesting to take a look at [this Ned Batchelder python solution](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712.html#e20071211T054956) and [a discussion of the topic on CodingHorror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/)

Comment: @R Nar, Not all keys are ints, that's why I said that some keys may look like D239, D97, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, yes.  The old, "Just put it in a natural order!" problem.

Translating an old hack that I got in Perl from Tye McQueen, something like this should work for strings:

```
import re

def replace_match(match):
    value = match.group(0)
    if value[0] == ".":
        return value
    else:
        return ("0"*(9-len(value))) + value

def replace_with_natural(string):
    return re.sub("(\.\d*|[1-9]\d{0,8})", replace_match, string)

items = ["hello1", "hello12", "foo12.1", "foo12.05", "hello3", "foo.12.12"]
print(sorted(items, key=replace_with_natural))
```

The idea is that we replace every number in the string with a number of fixed length that sorts lexicographically in the way we like.

Note that ANY function like this will run into stuff it handles poorly.  In this case, scientific notation is handled poorly.  But this will do what people expect with embedded numbers 99.99% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make sure to compare keys as ints instead of strings, when you're using strings they're sorted alphabetically, ie `'7' > '11'`. The easiest way to do this is to define your own custom comparison methods for your `foo` class:

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class foo:
    def __init__(self, key1, data1, data2):
        #all of these values are strings, even though some may be ints
        self.key = key1
        self.d1 = data1
        self.d2 = data2

    @staticmethod
    def _as_int(value):
        try:
            return int(value)
        except ValueError:
            return value

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self._as_int(self.key) < self._as_int(other.key)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._as_int(self.key) == self._as_int(other.key)

l1 = [foo('12', 'foo1', None),
      foo('8', 'qwer', None),
      foo('7', 'foo3', None),
      foo('13', 'foo2', None),
      foo('77', 'foo4', None),
      foo('12', 'foo5', None),
      foo('A', 'foo', None),
      foo('B', 'foo', None)]

for item in sorted(l1):
    print item.key, item.d1, item.d2
```

Which gives:

```
7 foo3 None
8 qwer None
12 foo1 None
12 foo5 None
13 foo2 None
77 foo4 None
A foo None
B foo None
```

If you know for sure that the `key` attribute will be numeric, you can simplify the code a little bit.

Comment: Hi @Bo Rico. Thanks, it works for numbers. I've also never seen functools before! 

Can this function be extended to the use case of keys such as A12, A8, A7, A13, etc? The current behavior still compares strings by digit.

Comment: The key is to have `_as_int` convert the string into an object that can be property ordered. If you're using some sort of structured text, you can return a tuple that'll get sorted. ie `A12XYZ` -> `('A', 12, 'XYZ')`, '77' -> `('', 77, '')`. How you split up the strip, which parts you induce/exclude and how you order them in the tuple will depend on how you want the objects to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting strings.  The string `'12'` comes before `'2'`, for example.  Cast them as numbers if you want to sort numerically.

Comment: As stated, I'm not just trying to sort strings. Some keys may have chars prepended.

Comment: @ZtoYi a char is a string, I was explaining why you got the behavior you got: you're sorting strings.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As per @zehnpaard
http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712.html#e20071211T054956
http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/

and @BlivetWidge
[Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)